# Kubuntu 16.04 no wifi driver not ethernet port

Tags: kubuntu, kubuntu-netbook

Hey guy how do I install the wifi drivers without internet to my laptop that recently installed kubuntu and wifi does not work. My laptop has not ethernet port and I do want to run kubuntu, help please.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a smartphone with an active internet connection? If you have, then you can use your phone's internet through USB cable. You only need to turn on USB tethering and connect it to your Kubuntu PC. Or another way is to connect through Bluetooth by turning on Bluetooth tethering.
To install wifi driver, first of all, check which brand's adapter you have through the command `lsusb`, you will get the list of all the USB devices installed on your computer.

[image]

Here, in my case, I have a Realtek adapter, so I have installed the RTL driver.
You may have Broadcom or maybe another adapter.